# How to disable checksums on ethernet card in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

How to disable checksums on ethernet card in Windows 10, preferably generaly (not hardware/driver specific)? I'm looking for Windows counterpart to

```
ethtool -K eth1 tx off
```

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to generate ethernet packets from scratch, with explicity wrong checksums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open the Device Manager.
- Locate your network adapter.
- Right-click -> Properties.
- Advanced Tab.

What the options is called will vary based on the NIC manufacturer and may not even be available if the NIC's driver doesn't support it.

On my system (Realtek adapter) it's labelled "TCP Checksum Offload" and there's one for IPv4 and one for IPv6.

[image: NIC Advanced Props]

Other similar name: "Offload Transmit TCP Checksum".

[Source](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Offloading)